# HTML generate URL from Input

Tags: html, input, hyperlink

i am working on a search function, herefore i need the value of an input to generate the final url (which shows the results)

Let's say the user enters the content he is looking for here:

`Name: <input type="text" id="myText">`

now i need to generate a hyperlink from
`http://constant/constant?query=NAME&someotherconstantthings`

here, the NAME needs to be replaced from the content of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use PHP, you could add a action to the Form Element to post the entered informations to the PHP file, then generate ur hyperlink.

```
<form action="phpfilename.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST['myText'];
$hyperlink = 'http://constant/constant?query='.$name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<form action="URL" method="get">
    Enter your name here: <input type="text" name="query" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

You need to replace the keyword URL with the path to the page which performs the search. You can remove the keyword URL if want to submit the form to the same page.

Comment: how can i replace the url if i dont know it/it is not constant

Comment: Replace `URL` with this `<?php echo $_REQUEST['url'];?>`. Now you can set the form url using the url you enter in your browser like this `http://www.example.com/document.php?url=/some-dir/some-file.php`.